# String with dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss format to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to convert a `nvarchar(max)` column to a `datetime` in SQL Server. The format is `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`, which I'd like to keep, however I'd like to change the type to `datetime`. I've found many similar questions about this conversion, but not with my particular format.

I've tried `CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), string_column, 121)`, however without luck. How can this be done? As example, I'd like to convert the string `26-11-2021 08:19:16` to datetime.

Comment: You're trying to convert it to an `nvarchar` from a `nvarchar`; it's *already* an `nvarchar`. Also if you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you'll see style `121` isn't `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`. The *real* problem here is your design; store date and time data as a date and time data type.

Comment: An `nvarchar(MAX)`, by the way, is a truly terrible choice of a data type for a date and time value. A date and time will *never* be up to **2GB** in size, and they are binary values, so they have no need to be able to store the full range of UTF-16 characters.

Comment: *"The format is `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`, which I'd like to keep"* `datetime` has no format, it's a binary number that stores a point in time. When you *display* it you can format it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DECLARE @InString NVARCHAR(20)='26-11-2021 08:19:16';
 SELECT @InString;
 SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@InString,105);
```

Could you please try if it is suitable for you

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0), '26-11-2021 08:19:16', 105);
/* Output: 2021-11-26 08:19:16 */
```

Recent versions of SQL Server also have [the `TRY_PARSE` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('26-11-2021 08:19:16' As datetime2(0) USING 'en-GB')
/* Output: 2021-11-26 08:19:16 */
```